# Django: ordering by specific backwared related property

Tags: python, django

I have two models:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, default='', db_index=True, unique=True)


class VideoTranslation(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, related_name='translations')
    language = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=settings.LANGUAGES)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
```

Video contains some infromation about video, Video translation contains translated names of these videos.

I want to get itmes from Video model in one of languages.

It is possible by sql query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM video_video IN join video_videotranslation ON video_video.id = video_videotranslation.video_id where video_videotranslation.language="en" ORDER BY video_videotranslation.name;
```

but I really want to avoid raw sql queries.

Is it possible to make this kind of query rellying only on Django ORM?

Comment: video.objects.select_related(depth=1).filter(videotranslation__language='en').order_by('videotranslation__name')

Comment: Why not use something like django-modeltranslation ? That with django-localeurl (or django 1.4) would save you quite an amount of work.

Comment: Modeltranslation is great app, but I have plenty of models and completed database structure which I got from previous develeoper(and it much more complex than in example). Converting it to modeltranslation format scare me a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, it will look like:

```
Video.objects.filter(translations__language='en').order_by('translations__name')
```

See [lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) for the syntax, and the [documentation of order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by).

Answer (score 1):

```
Video.objects.filter(translations__language__iexact='en').order_by('translations__name')
```